# Using png images from photoshop.

Tags: android, memory-management, png

So when i have images such as logos and backgrounds there not that big 30kbs roughly, but when i run the app on my phone there is some frame skipping and the app uses about 150mb of the phones memory. Just seems a lot for a blank activity with a background and a logo. I call them through an image view or set the layout background to the desired image. Could it be a photo shop issue??
Is it something to do with the scale of the images? 
I am still very new to this. Thanks

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?  Your app will decode each image to three or four bytes per pixel.

Comment: For instance the background in photo shop was 1080x1920 at 72dpi. Then all other images where designed based on that as the screen size. Yeah i did read something about decoding but didnt really understand how i could fix my issue from it.

Comment: 1080 * 1920 * 4 * 8 = 66355200 bytes (about 66MB), once decoded in memory.

Comment: So lower thr image canvas size to for instance 108x192 bit extreme i know but for example. Surely that cant be right??

Comment: Should i look into researching about decoding images?

Comment: You better use a color or a tileable image (so that it woulbe a small sized repeating tile) or even a 9 patch. Or a vector drawable. Or a gradient. Or even combinations of the aforementioned options. There are a lot of alternatives to using huge images.

Comment: Ok ill have a look into it and see what i can come up with. Thanks for the help and advice